# Como evito que mis fragmentos de bottom menu se mezclen con mi segunda activity?

Tags: android, activity, studio, transacciones, menu

Mi problema está en los replace, evito que mis fragmentos se mezclen entre si, sin embargo mi segunda activity (detalle_pelicula) se mezcla con el resto de mis fragments (fragment_inicio, fragment_favoritos, fragment_configuracion)

(MAIN ACTIVITY)

```
  BottomNavigationView menu = findViewById(R.id.bottom_menu);

        //inicializar el fragmento principal
        Fragment fragmentoInicio = new InicioFragment();
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contenedor, fragmentoInicio).commit();

        menu.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(item -> {

            Fragment fragmento;

            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.inicio:
                    fragmento = new InicioFragment();
                    break;

                case R.id.favoritos:
                    fragmento = new FavoritosFragment();
                    break;

                case R.id.configuracion:
                    fragmento = new ConfiguracionFragment();
                    break;
                default:
                    fragmento = new InicioFragment();
            }

            manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contenedor, fragmento).commit();

            return true;
        });
```

(DETALLE PELICULA ACTIVITY)

```
     //Declaracion de bottom menu
        BottomNavigationView menu = findViewById(R.id.bottom_menu);



    //Fragment manager
        FragmentManager fmanager = getSupportFragmentManager();

        menu.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(item -> {

            Fragment fragmento;

            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.inicio:
                    fragmento = new InicioFragment();
                    break;

                case R.id.favoritos:
                    fragmento = new FavoritosFragment();
                    break;

                case R.id.configuracion:
                    fragmento = new ConfiguracionFragment();
                    break;
                default:
                    fragmento = new InicioFragment();
            }

            fmanager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contenedord, fragmento).commit();

            return true;
        });

    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.i("metodos", "on destroy detalle");
    }


    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Log.i("metodos", "on pause detalle");
    }
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Log.i("metodos", "on start detalle");
    }
```

Mi main activity es destruido cuando hago click en el cardview de alguna pelicula y me envía al detalle de pelicula, lo mismo pasa cuando cambio de fragmento desde el main, el main se pausa, se destruye cada vez que hago click en el bottom menu.
Pero esto no sucede con el detalle pelicula, o bien no se como hacer que esto suceda, que la activity detalle se destruya y solo muestre los fragmentos como tal.

Answer (score 0):

Tu código tiene un patron de diseño de una sola Actividad en la que realizas transacción de Fragments, por lo tanto lo que sucede es que tu `BottomNavigationView` se encuentra en la Activity y en esta activity se realiza la transacción de Fragmentos, todos estos Fragmentos tendrán el `BottomNavigationView`.

La solución en este caso es realizar un método en tu `Activity`:

```
public void setBottomNavigationVisibility(int visibilidad) {
   //Cambia visibilidad de BottomNavigationView
   myBottomNavigationView.setVisibility(visibilidad);
}
```

de esta forma cuando te encuentres dentro del `Fragment` que no desees ver el `BottomNavigationView` puedes llamarlo de esta forma:

```
setBottomNavigationVisibility(View.GONE);
```

si deseas hacerlo visible nuevamente:

```
setBottomNavigationVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```